# How to create a relation between a SQLAlchemy model and a table with no model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, microservices, fastapi, alembic

I am working on micro-services, the base service is in Django and other services are in FastAPI.
All the services will share the same PostgreSQL database, the Employee model is in Django and and I want to establish a relation between the model Leave in FastApI with the Employee Model.

```py
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, JSON
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.sql import table, column

existing_employee_table = table('employee', column('id', Integer), )


class Leave(Base):
    __tablename__ = "leaves"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    leave_count = Column(JSON, nullable=False)

    employee_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("employee.id"), nullable=False)
    employee = relationship("employee", back_populates="leaves")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table needs to be in the same metadata instance as the model. Then the mapper can find its details to construct the relationship. You could declare it like this:

```py
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy import orm

engine = sa.create_engine(...)

Base = orm.declarative_base()

# Reflect the table into the metadata instance that contains the model.
existing_employee_table = sa.Table('employee', Base.metadata, autoload_with=engine)

class Leave(Base):
    ...

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: It also worked with alembic migrations, 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi @snakecharmerb, how to create a relation with it, getting this error

{ArgumentError}relationship 'employee' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)

while generating an object 
db_leave = models.Leave(**leave.model_dump())

issue with this line
employee = relationship("employee", back_populates="leaves")

Comment: I think here we may have reached the limits of this approach: we've satisfied the mapper, but the ORM is not fooled. I think you need to map a class to the table.

Comment: Yeah, I have tried it with mapper class and it worked with it. Thanks for the help again.